# Trying to capture and use a response from script that is ran inside BASH

Tags: shell-script

I'm creating a function that runs a script and outputs that to a file.  Once that happens it reads that file line by line executing a stop.  I'd like to add an if condition that if the server fails to start it kill -9 $pid.  It's not working.

```bsh
function stop_server() {
     su -s /bin/bash user /usr/local/server/bin/server list | sed "1,2 d" >>jvms
     while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
     do
         su -s /bin/bash user /usr/local/server/bin/server stop $p
         if [[ $(su -s /bin/bash user /usr/local/server/bin/server stop $p)= 'Server $p stop failed. Check server logs for details.' ]];
         then
               PID="ps -ef|grep -v grep |grep '$p' | awk '{print $2}'"
               kill -9 $PID
         fi
     done
}
```

I'd like to capture the results of the server stop $p and then I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
      if [ $results = 'Server $p stop failed. Check server logs for details.' ]; then
         PID="ps -ef|grep -v grep |grep '$p' | awk '{print $2}'"
         kill -9 $PID
      fi
```

Comment: You're doing the same operation "su -s /bin/bash user /usr/local/server/bin/server stop $p" twice in your first script, before the conditon and inside it. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
 PID=$(ps -ef|grep -v grep |grep '$p' | awk '{print $2}')
```

But IMHO you should find a way to get the PID of the process by more direct means. Don't they leave a ".pid" file somewhere? And do you need to `su` to issue the stop?